# Is Craft a good fit for my project?

Tags: discussion

This seems to come up from time to time, and I'm on the fence as to whether it's an acceptable question. Here's the most recent example...

- [Is Craft a good fit for a project w/ social network features?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/4149/45)

So maybe we can sort it out once and for all... **Is Craft SE a reasonable place for people to inquire about whether Craft fits the bill for their project?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this kind of input from fellow developers is exceptionally helpful when starting a project. But, I do not think these kinds of questions are a good fit for the StackExchange site for a these two reasons...

1. The answers that get posted tend to be opinion based and are not ones where there is a clear CORRECT answer. The answer to the question you linked is a great example of what I'm talking about... It starts with "It really depends" and goes in one direction and then ends in another.
2. Answering such questions can require an intimate understanding of the project's functionality specs/details which can lead to lots of "clarifying" comments being asked and answered. The site is meant to be question/answer so that back and forth isn't a great fit.

Comment: Thanks Anna, this is much more inline with what my gut was telling me. That type of question tends to feel like a "what's your opinion" type of question. And +1 for mentioning the need for clarity... how could you recommend a specific CMS/platform without the clearest definition of project scope?

Comment: All that being said... does it make sense for us to create a new "off-topic close reason" for a question like that?

Comment: I don't think we need another. I'd file under "primarily opinion-based" as the reason.

Comment: Works for me... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there's no better place asking these questions than here in Craft SE. It's not just about code!

All I'd do is to give them all the same tag. So that new users can better find and read through them. Maybe this helps a little to avoid duplicates.

Comment: +1 Interesting suggestion about tagging them!

Comment: Yeh? But I've no good name for the tag, @Lindsey. Sorry.

Comment: Lol, no worries. We'll come up with something. :)